# Angular2: Add multiple directives globally

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'd like to add @angular2-material directives to the "global" directives. In order to do so, I currently have the following bootstrap function:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: MdToolbar, multi: true }),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: MdButton, multi: true }),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: MdInput, multi: true }),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: MdCheckbox, multi: true }),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: MdRadioButton, multi: true }),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: MdRadioGroup, multi: true }),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: MdIcon, multi: true }),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: MD_SIDENAV_DIRECTIVES, multi: true }),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES, multi: true }),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES, multi: true })
]);
```

Is there a way to do this in 1 go instead of adding them individually in multiple "repeated" lines?

Answer (score 0):

**update**

Adding directives globally is not supported anymore since 2.0.0 final.

See also [Declaring multiple components in @ngModule Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738984/declaring-multiple-components-in-ngmodule-angular-2/40739375#40739375)

**original**

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: [
      MdToolbar,
      MdButton,
      MdInput,
      MdCheckbox,
      MdRadioButton,
      MdRadioGroup,
      MdIcon,
      MD_SIDENAV_DIRECTIVES,
      MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES,
      MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES], 
    multi: true })
]);
```

With the new introduced modules this can be done easier in RC.5. Just export them from a module an import the module. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html