# Declaring multiple components within @ngModule in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am developing a large application using `Angular 2` and `ASP.net` MVC.
I have approximately 120 components in my application which are all declared in @ngModule declarations block:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [Component1, Component2, Component3, ..., Component120]
})
```

Is there a mechanism where I can shorten this?

Comment: Breakdown your application to smaller smaller `module/submodule`, think in such a way that each module should not have more than `10-15` components, the you can create NgModule for each `submodule` & load them lazily via router feature(this can also add boost in application performance).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can build a shared module and add the components to this module, then you only have to add the shared module to `imports: [MySharedModule]` and all components and directives exported by `MySharedModule` become available to the importing module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ Component1,   Component2,   Component3....      Component120 
],
  exports: [ Component1,   Component2,   Component3....      Component120 ],
})
```

export  class MySharedModule {}

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, MySharedModule]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, will implement in this way.

Comment: You have `imports: [ CommonModule ],` twice.

Answer (score -2):

I'm afraid there is not a shorter way to achieve what you are trying to do.

But if it is possible, you can divide your application in multiple parts. This means you will have more than one app.module.ts.