# Angular 2 using share components(removing x type is declared in two modules)

Tags: angular

I have 3 modules : ControlsModule, genericManagementNameModule & SharedModule.
I want to use a use a component(DropDown) from the ControlsModule in a component that's part of the genericManagementNameModule.
I used to declare the (DropDown) in both modules, but since updating angular it gives that "is declared in two modules" error.
Where do i need to declare the DropDown component?

**Controls Module**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { MaterialDatePickerComponent } from './Controls/MaterialDatePicker/MaterialDatePickerComponent';
import { DropDownControl } from './Controls/DropDown/DropDownControl';
import { MultiColumnDropDownControl } from './Controls/MultiColumnDropDown/MultiColumnDropDownControl';
import { MultipleSelectionDropDownControl } from './Controls/MultipleSelectionDropDown';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [MaterialDatePickerComponent, MultiColumnDropDownControl, MultipleSelectionDropDownControl, DropDownControl],
    exports: [MaterialDatePickerComponent, DropDownControl, MultiColumnDropDownControl, MultipleSelectionDropDownControl,
        CommonModule, FormsModule]
})
export class ControlsModule { }
```

**InventoryEquipment Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SharedModule } from './../shared.module';
import { ControlsModule } from './../Assets/Controls.Module';

import { inventoryEquipmentRouting } from './inventoryEquipment.routing';
import { InventoryEquipmentComponent } from './List/inventoryEquipment.component';
import { InventoryEquipmentComponentDefault } from './View/inventoryEquipmentDefault.component';



@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, inventoryEquipmentRouting, SharedModule, ControlsModule], 
    declarations: [InventoryEquipmentComponent, InventoryEquipmentComponentDefault],
    exports: [InventoryEquipmentComponent, InventoryEquipmentComponentDefault, ControlsModule],
})
export class InventoryEquipmentModule { }
```

So i'm basically trying to use DropDownControl from ControlsModule in InventoryEquipmentComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare it in one module and add it also to `exports: [...]`

then add this module to `imports: [...]` wherever you want to use that component.

See also [Declaring multiple components in @ngModule Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738984/declaring-multiple-components-in-ngmodule-angular-2/40739375#40739375)

Comment: But if i make declare it in my ControlsModule, than i import this module into ShareModule, can i export it from ShareModule? Or do i have to import ControlsModule in my genericManagementNameModule?

Comment: You can re-export single components and directives or the whole module. Just list them in `exports: [...]` and importers of this module will have it available.

Comment: So i have done the following thing. I have the DropDown component declared & exported in the control module. Then i import this module in my genericManagementNameModule. In this module, i have a component declared, a component in which i'm trying to use the DropDown component, but it still has template error due to the 'DropDown' component not being part of this module.

Comment: Please add code to your question, not in comments. Code in comments is unreadable - just in case this is what you planned to do ;-)

Comment: Please post the code in your question. What you explain sounds correct, but there might be something wrong I can't see from your eplanation.

Comment: Okay, i shall edit the original post with code and perhaps you'll see what i'm doing wrong. Should be done in ~5minutes.

Comment: Please add a comment when you're done, so I'll get notified.

Comment: You don't need to export `ControlsModule` when `DropDownControl` is only directly used inside `InventoryEquipmentModule`. To me all looks correct. No idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Found it. Was the fact that i didnt add schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] in the module.

Comment: Interesting, I got the impression that you get an error message that it is missing if there are unknown elements. But if it solves your problem :D Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Sadly now, even tho it doesn't give any error, it no longer actually loads the component, also giving "No value accesor for form control with name:..". And if i add ngDefaultControl, it no longer gives the error, but no component is loaded, getting only am empty small square.

Comment: Doesn't sound like this is related to the shared module. Either you are missing an import like `FormsModule` in the module where you use this control, or there is something wrong with your form setup.